# Problems populating a fragment list

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have a SherlockFragmentActivity class that collects values from a server and loads it in to my database. This SherlockFragmentActivity as 3 Fragment called the Book, Video and Audios. Each of them are meant to show values that were downloaded into the db. By challenge now is when I open my UI i dont get to see the values on the fragments not until I start clicking each fragment before the values get populated into the list in the fragment. And I even notice a continuous addition of this values. My fragment class is pasted below.

```
    public class BooksFragment extends SherlockListFragment{

    TextView textview = null;
    String CategoryID = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listBooks = null;

    IDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = null;

    Activity activity = null;
    Context context = null;

    ListAdapter adapter = null;


    public BooksFragment(){

        super();
    }


     @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.books, container, false);
        // do your view initialization heres
        textview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        return view;
      }



     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         listBooks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

     }


      @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();


            Bundle bundle =this.getArguments();

            if(bundle != null){
                CategoryID = bundle.getString("CategoryID");           
            }

            this.initializeComponents();
            this.populateListView();
      }


      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
          super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

          activity = getActivity();
          context = activity.getBaseContext();

          databaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(context);


      }


      //Now we are going to initialize components of the fragment
      private void initializeComponents(){

          ListView listview = getListView();
          listview.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
      }


      //list item click listener
        private OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


         };


         //This method would be used to collect content from the database and populate the listview item
         private void populateListView(){
             MedicalBookModel[] booksmodel = this.databaseHelper.ReturnBooks(CategoryID);

             if(booksmodel != null){
                 for(MedicalBookModel book : booksmodel){

                     HashMap<String,String> bookMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
                     bookMap.put(MedicalBookModel.MedicalBookModel_ID, book.getID());
                     bookMap.put(MedicalBookModel.MedicalBookModel_Name,book.getName());

                     Log.i("values",book.getName());

                     listBooks.add(bookMap);
                 }
             }

             adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, listBooks,R.layout.list_book,new String[]{ "ID","Name"}, new int[]{ R.id.bookId, R.id.bookName});
             setListAdapter(adapter);
         }


}
```

Comment: A don't use listFragment so from my point of view i would recommend you to use A Fragment with a ListView with a BaseAdapter

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am really greateful. I would let you know how it goes.

Comment: It is still the same thing. I tried a normal Fragment same story. I think it as to do with when the values is called to be added to the fragment list. is there a way I can load the list in the fragment from my activity. So that as soon as the activity is loaded. The fragment is populated

Comment: Well I think. I have an idea of how I can do this. I am think of collecting the values to be populated in the fragment from the activity. So I now pass this values when creating the fragment. But I am loading my list as ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>. I dont know how to as this item as a Bundle.

Comment: I have been able to pass it into my fragment. now I am trying to use it up now to populate my list. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have several solutions :

**1-** Using the Application instance singleton which is global

**2-** Creating your own global class to manage your data

**3-** Use a service bound to the activity (or not) and call backs (maybe intent and broadcast receivers)

**4-** Pass your object as parceable in argument when adding the fragment

Note that sometimes you will need to invalidate views to force datas to refresh

**EXEMPLE OF PARCEABLE OBJECT**

```
public class ImageObject implements Parcelable {
    /**
     * ATTRIBUTES
     */
    protected String    _idPicture;
    protected String    _idAlbum;
    protected String    _name;
    protected String    _fileName;
    protected String    _imageUrl;
    protected String    _hierarchy;

    public ImageObject(String _idPicture, String _idAlbum, String _name, String _fileName, String _imageUrl, String _hierarchy) {

        super();
        this._idPicture = _idPicture;
        this._idAlbum = _idAlbum;
        this._name = _name;
        this._fileName = _fileName;
        this._imageUrl = _imageUrl;
        this._hierarchy = _hierarchy;
    }

    public ImageObject(Parcel in) {

        String[] data = new String[6];
        in.readStringArray(data);
        this._idPicture = data[0];
        this._idAlbum = data[1];
        this._name = data[2];
        this._fileName = data[3];
        this._imageUrl = data[4];
        this._hierarchy = data[5];
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator  CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
                                                        public ImageObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {

                                                            return new ImageObject(in);
                                                        }

                                                        public ImageObject[] newArray(int size) {

                                                            return new ImageObject[size];
                                                        }
                                                    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this._idPicture, this._idAlbum, this._name, this._fileName, this._imageUrl, this._hierarchy });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I would love step 4. But I tried passing values I did not see a method that allows me to pass ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> in my Bundle object.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how it could be passed

Comment: Did you try "intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra( "key", arraylist );"

Comment: Bundle don't seem to have to that method above. When passing values to fragment we use bundle instead.

Comment: bundle.putParcelableArrayList("", booksmodel); Hav been trying this but I am having errors now. I am confused here, dont know how to pass ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> into the bundle.

Comment: In eclipse Ide it underlines it. booksmodel is an ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> object.

Comment: So you suggesting i change the hash Map to a placeable object.

Comment: If i where yo i would clearly create an object to "manage" the hashmap (add, remove, clear, instanciate... )

Comment: Using types like hashmap like that in transitions can be pretty confusing, you should try to do some work on your data model

Comment: I have just created a Placeable object to replace with the HashMap.

Comment: Your model is fine I guess. It depends on what you need it for :)

Comment: I intend using it with a list view that as item with two text views

Comment: am almost tru. I am still coding. Thanks for your time. Atleast I have passing it tru the bundle now.

Comment: Ok nice the hear that. I really think you should review your data model, interfaces, data passing ...etc

Comment: While trying to pass ArrayList<PlaceHolder object> into my SimpleAdapter eclipse threw an error.

Comment: Don't use simpleadapter, better use BaseAdapter

Comment: It woooooorrrrkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeed. Thanks bro you are the man you made me happpppppppppy. Thanks alot. Well but I still used the SimpleAdapter. I simple converted the Placeable ArrayList to HashMap ArrayList in my fragments. Thanks alot my friend you made me happy.

Comment: Well I would love to ask you a question if you are informed about a particular subject. It phonegap bro. sometimes I get tempted to use phonegap instead of native. can phone gap create instant messaging apps like Black berry messager and whats app.

Comment: The only advantages that phone gap has are the "cross placeform", and the fast developpement. A native application will be much much faster, much responsive/prettier .. etc so i would always advice doing native code for iphone/android. Since blackberry is dying and windows phone is not taking of XD